# Why can't I Sync Picasa Web Albums?

Tags: sync, htc-hero, picasa

Device: T-Mobile G2 (UK) / HTC Hero
OS: 2.1

I would like to Sync Picasa Web Albums, like on this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PIfjt3pye5c. However, the option is not present - only contacts, Google Reader, Google Mail, calendar. I've tried visiting Picasa Web Albums site on my phone browser, and re-starting the phone, but it's not there. How can I enable it?

Edit (28th Jan) - I raised a ticket on support.htc.com about this a while ago. Here are their responses...

- "Dave": "Do you have the Picasa option showing in the accounts and sync folder of Settings on your phone, please?"
- "Dave": "Can you confirm you are running at least Android 2.1 on your handset?"
- "Richard": "Christopher, your email has been passed to myself for further action as there has been no activity on it since the 22nd Jan. Picasa is a 3rd party application and you will need to install additional software from the Android Market to enable this functionality. (Picasa Album Sync is not pre-installed on your phone.) "
- "Richard": "The picasa sync is not pre-installed on any of the HTC handsets running Android 2.x. I have checked several android phones running 2.1 and 2.2 that we have here and none of them have a Picasa sync option. I will pass on this information to the developers and inform them that a customer has asked for this function to be included on the phones. This may lead to it being implemented in a future update. In the meantime if you want that functionality then you will need to obtain 3rd party software which can provide it."

I'm not sure why Dave asked those questions, when Richard is adament that the functionality doesn't exist. Does anyone have any examples of Picasa working on HTC handsets running Android 2.x?

Comment: Don't see it on my 2.2 Evo either so I can't say it's truly on all 2.1 and above devices.

Comment: Is it a Gmail or Google Apps account?

I don't have "Sync Picasa Web Album" in my Google Apps account, though I do have it in Gmail.

Comment: It's my primary @gmail.com account.

Comment: I have a Samsung Intercept, and I also don't see an option to sync Picasa Web Albums with the Gallery app on my phone. I do have the Gallery app, and I can upload photos from the Gallery to Picasa Web Albumns (And to Facebook and Dropbox). But this 'sync' option is not there.

Comment: @Chris: Does your Gallery app look anything like the App in the video, with the smooth animation and the flowing icons? The Gallery app on my phone has none of those fancy animations-- it's much simpler looking. I've read elsewhere that there are two different Gallery apps for Android 2.1, although I cannot find a link at the moment.

Comment: Do have the stock Android 3D Gallery app? (someone has given this answer already) The HTC gallery app doesn't sync to Picassa in the same way.

Comment: @Stefan  No, I have the 'simpler' looking one. The frustrating thing is that I'm 99% sure I previously saw the option to sync Picasa, but never used it.

Comment: Tier 1 support personnel very often don't have any deep knowledge of the products they support. More than likely he's working off a script.

Comment: This problem affects more then just HTC phones. Samsung Intercept is also affected, as are other models (according to my google searches).

Answer (score 3):

Here's what you have to do:

1. Go into the Gallery
2. Long click on a photo, choose "Share" and then choose "Picasa"
3. On the "upload photo" screen add a new album, then upload the photo (it doesn't matter what album, you just need to add one to create a new folder in Picasa.  This is the trick to linking your phone and your Picasa Web Albums).
4. After it's done uploading (check on the web to make sure it worked) from the home screen hit the menu button and go to Settings > Accounts & Sync > Click on your gmail address that is associated with Picasa.  Now you should see "Sync Picasa Web Albums" in the menu.

If that doesn't work.  Try restarting after that process, and then if that still doesn't work... :o(

Comment: I should mention that I had the same problem as you on my Moto Droid, and this fixed it for me so HTC may be different, but I'll bet its the same problem, an account linking problem.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed instructions. Sadly, this didn't work for me. I'm sure it's an account linking problem, but just not sure how to get the accounts linked except for deleting/recreating my account.

Comment: Did it let you create a new folder on Picasa from your gallery app?

Comment: Matt; 1) I have "Photos" not "Gallery"; 4) I see the new album name and photo in picasaweb, but even after restart I still only see contacts/Reader/Mail/calendar in the Android sync options. I've had a ticket open with htc.com's official support for a month now, with no info.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install the Gallery 3D app. It's not available on the market but here is a [link for the APK](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=653503) which you will need to download to your SD card and install manually (use Astro, or similar).

(Dmitriy already gave this answer but I had the link & wasn't sure you'd seen my comment so I've added this as an answer too)

Answer (score 2):

I have a T-Mobile Vibrant and when I was running the Stock Samsung 2.1 TouchWiz I did not have this option to sync to Picasa. But I am now running a 2.2 ROM and I can sync it. I would say to try to log in to picasa via your PC first, and maybe upload a photo, create a gallery, things like that. Then go back in to your device and see if you can sync it.

You will go in to your google account in Accounts & Sync and it should have the option in there to sync. you do not have to add another account on the main Accounts and sync screen.

It will also work with Google Apps accounts, if they have been upgraded to the "full google account" by the apps administrator.

Comment: Thanks - I've even tried creating a public profile, and having pictures publically viewable on the web, but no sign of it yet. I can upload individual pics from the "Photos" app to Picasa (all folders I create online are visible on the phone!), but not sync through the OS.

Comment: I've tried logging out & logging in on PC & Phone, creating gallery from phone, uploading gallery from phone, etc. Still no success here.

Answer (score 2):

There is an application called 3D Gallery. This application supports using Picasa from the google account. After installing and launching it will ask you for permission to access picasa and then you will browse the online library as if its local with options to copy.

Comment: I can't seem to find (Android 2.1). Who's the developer, and is there a link?

Comment: @Chris get the APK here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=653503