# HTC EVO Does Not Sync Google Calendar

Tags: sync, calendar, htc-evo

I'm an experienced Android user and recently my Dad picked up a HTC EVO. I set him up with all the Google services and apps like Gmail, Contacts and Calendar. I exported all of his contacts and appointments out of Outlook to CSV and uploaded them to Google so they can sync down to his EVO. Unfortunately when I go to his Google account sync settings, his phone does not show the option to sync his Google Calendar. The exact option I'm talking about is under (from the home screen) Settings -> Accounts & sync -> your Google account. The phone shows Books, Contacts, and Gmail but the option for calendar is missing. Is this the case on all EVO's?

I have [a screen capture of my phone](http://www.flickr.com/photos/matthewrileyusa/5390841537/) (HTC Incredible) that has the option below that I'm talking about. His HTC EVO does not have it for some reason. Is this a Sprint restriction? Any ideas on how to add it?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd make sure that he's done something with Calendar through the web interface, such as add a custom calendar, and then try to add the account to the phone again. To do this you need to clear the data for all Google apps -- Accounts and Sync, Gmail, Google Framework Services, etc. -- and then re-add the account.

I don't believe this is EVO-specific, it seems sometimes Google just doesn't correctly link the accounts sometimes (for example, this question has the same problem except for Picasa: [Why can't I Sync Picasa Web Albums?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4015/sync-picasa-web-albums-option-not-there)).

Comment: You don't have to do a factory reset.  See my answer [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1841/how-can-i-remove-the-default-google-account-on-my-phone).  Basically clearing all the data from all the Google apps as you suggest brings you back to the initial Account Setup.

Comment: This Matt says thanks to the Matt's on this thread. I'll get back to my Dad and see if it works. Results will be posted.

Comment: Confirmed: Clearing the data for all Google apps fixed this issue. The calendar is now syncing down to my Dad's EVO. I *think* the root cause was that he logged into his EVO before he had used Google Calendar web for the first time so there was no data for the service to sync.

Comment: Great, glad it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I had just read today about this same problem on a Galaxy S but can't find the post.  The post claimed that after adding a second Google account the "Sync Calendar" option appear for both account.

Comment: Yes adding second google account made it work. Thank You!