# Enable Picasa albums in Android gallery

Tags: sync, picasa

I can't enable Picasa sync.

I checked out [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4015/why-cant-i-sync-picasa-web-albums) but on the 3rd step I can't download my image. Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

I've enabled all Google syncronizations and installed the G+ app.

I use Android 2.3.5 and HTC Wildfire S.

Comment: @Al Everett thanks, you added screenshot to post